# Do linq queries re-execute if no changes occured?

Tags: c#, linq

I was reading up on LINQ. I know that there are deferred and immediate queries. I know with deferred types running the query when it's enumerated allows any changes to the data set to be reflected in each enumeration. But I can't seem to find an answer if there's a mechanism in place to prevent the query from running if no changes occurred to the data set since the last enumeration.

I read on MSDN referring to LINQ queries:

> Therefore, it follows that if a query is enumerated twice it will be executed twice.

Have I overlooked an obvious - but...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, there is none. Actually, that's not *quite* true - some LINQ providers will spot trivial but common examples like:

```
int id = ...
var customer = ctx.Customers.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
```

and will intercept that via the identity-manager, i.e. it will check whether it has a matching record already in the context; if it does: it doesn't execute anything.

You should note that the re-execution also has nothing to do with whether or not data has changed; it will re-execute (or not) *regardless*.

There are two take-away messages here:

- don't iterate *any* enumerable more than once: not least, it isn't guaranteed to *work at all*
- if you want to buffer data, *put it into a list/array*

So:

```
var list = someQuery.ToList();
```

will never re-execute the query, no matter how many times you iterate over `list`. Because `list` is not a query: it is *a list*.

A third take-away would be:

- if you have a context that lives long enough that it is *interesting* to ask about data migration, then you are probably holding your data-context for *far, far* too long - they are intended to be short-lived

Comment: Isn't `don't iterate *any* enumerable more than once: not least, it isn't guaranteed to *work at all*` a bit pessimistic?

Comment: Your short answer of no is indeed correct. I think, when speaking in general about LINQ, some of what you provided may not be exactly true. For instance with LINQ to Objects it makes plenty of sense why you'd run queries multiple times and perhaps with large gaps of time in between. So I thought it might be different in some cases. Before I asked I watched one in debug missing the `Results View` which says "Expanding the Results View will enumerate the IEnumerable" which, to me, proves you're right in general when it comes to executing. Thanks!

Comment: @Bobby the point I was trying to make is that even in LINQ-to-Objects, it is not *guaranteed* to work more than once

Comment: Would it be possible to point me to a link for specifics? That's a break from the C# book I've been reading in both explanation and practice. It's also contrary to what *is* happening in my code. But it's a simple test app. I don't know of specific situations I could create to scrutinize it to determine if it's *guaranteed* to work.

Comment: @Bobby sure, how about an iterator block over a network socket? Or an IDataReader? Or just over a Random instance?

Comment: OK. I guess I need to re-think my vision of the design and look into the best practices. Thanks again.